# What is the best method to summarise my data and add a new attribute?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to declare that VARIABLE is euqal to the last part of a string in my 'campaign' column.

My campaign column looks like this:

live_c_account_p_search_ct_dsa_l_location

I want to be able to extract the text following *l* and create a new column which I can later group by.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Either of the below approaches should be fine.

```
with data as (
    select 'a_b_c_d' as campaign union all
    select 'x_y_z'  union all 
    select 'live_c_account_p_search_ct_dsa_l_location'
)
select 
    campaign,
    regexp_extract(campaign, '.*_(.*)') as method1,
    array_reverse(split(campaign,'_'))[safe_ordinal(1)] as method2
from data
```